# Как избавится от подергивания при смене позиции блока?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

При скроле после "соприкосновения" блоков красный блок должен сдвинуться, но есть постоянные подергивания из за этого. Есть ли какое то решение, что бы такого избежать?
[Пример](https://codepen.io/Genexys/pen/QaKryR)

```js
function collision($div1, $div2) {
  var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
  var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
  var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
  var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
  var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;
}


window.onscroll = function() {
  var recommendedBlock = $('.box1');

  var footerBlock = $('.box2');
  if (collision(footerBlock, recommendedBlock)) {
    recommendedBlock.addClass('touch');
  } else {
    recommendedBlock.removeClass('touch');
  }
};
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000vh;
}

.box1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 8px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box1.touch {
  top: 190px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

p.s.
В практике у меня это фиксированное меню и при соприкосновении с футером менюха должна съехать, что бы не заезжать на футер

Comment: Опиши проблему подробнее, а то у тебя пример на столько кривой, что не понять, что тебе надо и что именно не получается...

Comment: @Air Ну я написал, что блок дергается. Надо что бы не дергался

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `transition` к `.box1`:

```js
function collision($div1, $div2) {
  var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
  var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
  var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
  var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
  var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;
}


window.onscroll = function() {
  var recommendedBlock = $('.box1');

  var footerBlock = $('.box2');
  if (collision(footerBlock, recommendedBlock)) {
    recommendedBlock.addClass('touch');
  } else {
    recommendedBlock.removeClass('touch');
  }
};
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000vh;
}

.box1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 8px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.box1.touch {
  top: 190px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: kizoso, вроде бы не то...  у тебя красный вообще не двигается

Comment: да, как вариант, я думал об этом, но хотелось бы более функциональное решение)